# Azure application gateway back-end pool load-balancer

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

We have configured application gateway with a backend pool which has multiple targets. We see that by default does load balancing. Is backend pools are load balanced by default with round robin? Is there any way we can configure it for weighted load balancing?

Comment: When the application gateway selects the backend pool, it sends the request to one of the healthy backend servers in the pool (y.y.y.y). The health of the server is determined by a health probe. If the backend pool contains multiple servers, the application gateway uses a round-robin algorithm to route the requests between healthy servers. This load balances the requests on the servers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/how-application-gateway-works

Comment: @DanielBjörk thanks missed out the sentence completely while reading.